# Red Badges in Collapsibles using materializecss

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm using materializecss and I want to use Badges in Collapsibles as the example on their website: http://materializecss.com/badges.html

The only difference is that I want to use red badges and i'm adding
class="new badge red" but it seems that collapsible-header is braking the alignment. here is the code:

https://jsbin.com/kumamalupu/1/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="grey lighten-2">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><span class="new badge red">4</span><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><span class="badge">1</span><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a fix to show the red badge correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was sloved: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3952

We will have to use the latest master version to use this fix.

So it is not released yet.